# Rails Routes - match

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a url http://localhost:3000/cars/2/wheels/5/airs/6

Routes.rb

```
resources :cars do
  resources :wheels do      
    resources :airs do  
      resources :oxygens
...
```

I want this URL to look like `http://localhost:3000/track/6` in the browser
Environment Rails 3.0.9

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create nested resources like this. I think you just have to use `resources :airs, :as => "track", :only => [:show]` and there you go if I have understood what you want.

Or you can use match `'track/:id', :to => 'airs#show'`.

Comment: The issue is that all these models are scoped. In the actual question it did not come out right. So its something like cars has wheels, wheels has air. And I want only the AIR's show method to become track.

Comment: So you can use `resources :airs, :as => "track", :only => [:show]`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Track model that belongs to a car, air, and oxygen model.

From the command-line use:

```
 ./script/generate model track car_id:integer air_id:integer oxygen_id:integer

 rake db:migrate
```

Then update your `track.rb` model:

```
 class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :car
   belongs_to :air
   belongs_to :oxygen
 end
```

Finally, add this as a route to `routes.rb`

```
 map.resources :tracks
```

Then, if you just add a track which belongs to the items you are looking for, you'll be able to navigate to it.  E.g., in `./script/console`, type:

```
 Track.new(:car_id => 2, :air_id => 5, :oxygen_id => 6)
```

Then navigate to:

```
 http://localhost:3000/tracks/1
```

That should be what you're looking for.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I think he just wanted to show airs as track and with your solution tracks don't create automatically.

Comment: Ha.. Right ! This should work. Nice... But is there just a routes match solution possible on lines of match 'track' => 'airs#show', :as => :track ..... of course this does not work.